# VC++2010 Automatically generate method stub or prototype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to C++ and Visual Studio, coming from Java and Eclipse;

Say I write a new method for a class. Is there a shortcut or some quick way to automatically add the method prototype to the class definition in the header?

Likewise, if i add a new method prototype to the header, is there a shortcut to generate a method stub in the implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if VS 2010 has this feature, previous versions did not.  But the problem can be addressed by 3rd party extensions. [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) has the commands "Create Declaration" and "Create Implementation".

Comment: "Move Implementation to Source File" is also handy:  you can define everything in the header for convenience then quickly move it all to a source file.

Comment: Also "Create from Usage" and "Implement Interface"

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at Visual Assist X. Looks quite good. It adds a lot of automation that I'm used to from Eclipse, but at a high price. I think I'll stick to good old copy/paste for now.